# how can i remove space between words in string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, string, for-loop, char

I need to remove the spaces in the string **"ab cde fg hijk lmn op"** without using "j".

I have tried this,

```
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == ' ') {
            output.append('j');
        } else {
            output.append(c);
        }
    }
```

So that output will be,

`abcdefghijklmnop`

Comment: What do you expect?

Comment: i expect to see this "abcdefghijklmnop"

Comment: What do you mean by `without using "j"`?

Comment: If you don't want the `j` why are you appending it?

Comment: it was like an example

Comment: “an example” for what? Your comment doesn’t explain anything. You have a statement which explicitly appends an obsolete `j` and removing that statement will give you the intended result without the `j`. So why did you insert that statement?

Comment: i tried to remove j, and it wasnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the spaces, simply:

```
str = str.replace(" ", "");
```

This replaces space with nothing.

Comment: @Dmitry no problem, consider upvoting / marking as correct;>

Comment: You may want to start that code with `str = ...` to avoid confusion with immutability of string.